# How do i detect Alt + Tab Key and then close the form?

Tags: vb.net

I want to close my form when Alt + Tab is pressed. However, The form is somehow not registering the key combination.

i have tried to use the Me.KeyUp event to detect the keys

```
Private Sub Menu_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
        Select Case e.KeyData
            Case (Keys.Alt + Keys.Tab)
                Close()
        End Select
End Sub
```

How can it be done ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible because `Alt + Tab` is a special windows combination. Can you use some other key combination.

Comment: That's usually the `ESC` key. One key press. A common one. Maybe you want to handle the Form's `Deactivate` event, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way

```
    Dim myval As Integer     'this is global variable declare
    Private Sub Menu_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
            Select Case e.KeyData
                Case (Keys.Alt)
                    myval = 1 
                Case (Keys.Tab)
                    If myval = 1  Then
                        Me.Close()
                    End If
            End Select
    End Sub
```

May be my syntax in not correct, please edit it if anything is notok.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  As in my comment `Alt+Tab` **would** not work. So try something else like `Alt+Q`. Put this code under the Form's keydown event.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Q AndAlso e.Modifiers = Keys.Alt) Then
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the form's  Set KeyPreview to True for it to respond to the key events, but since  Alt + Tab is a special windows combination the key events will not be fired.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around this problem using this method-

> That's usually the ESC key. One key press. A common one. Maybe you want to handle the Form's deactivate event, instead. – Jimi

I used the forms deactivate event to close it, since Alt+Tab is basically deactivating the form!
(A workaround because Alt+Tab as keystrokes were not detected by any means, as mentioned by
the last two answers.)

My final code looks like this -

```
Private Sub Menu_Deactivate(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Deactivate
    If loaded = true Then
        Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

I had to check if loaded (a boolean i declared to be set to true when everything is loaded)
to be true because my form opens one other form while loading, which inadvertently deactivated the main form and closed it!

Thank you so much for helping me everyone!!

Edit: I needed to clarify that the second form is always behind my main form so it is never really clicked on. I did this as a workaround to have aero blur in my application without a bug i experienced while applying it to the main form - it is too light, so text is unreadable. So i set another form to show aero blur and always stay behind my main form, whose opacity I have set to 0.88. This gives me a lot of control over the look of the blur.

Comment: The question is, WHY would you want to do this? Why provide a user with unexpected behavior for a key press combination that they expect something else to happen?

Comment: My application is a sort of thing users don't want to stay on for long - a sort of start menu. So key combinations that deactivate the form are expected to close it

Comment: Also It should behave such that clicks outside it also close the form, like the windows start menu. SInce i found the deactivate event handles both of the things, it was the best solution i could manage